# How to multiply two functions in python

Tags: python

I'm writing code for find parameter and area of different 2D objects. I decide to use local functions for this or the code become deep nested code. when I run this code it's says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'"

```
#Area Of Rectangle Section
def rectanglearea(a, b):
    length = a
    width = b
    #area = length * width
    print ("")
    print ("Formula = Length X Width")
    #print ("Area Of This Rectangle Is: ", area)
```

```
#Length local function
def length (a):
    length = input ("Input Length: ")
    lengthLoop = 1
    while lengthLoop == 1:
        try :
            length = float (length)
            break
        except:
            print ("Invalid input please TRYT AGAIN !!")
            continue
```

```
#Width local function
def width (a):
    width = input ("Input Width: ")
    widthLoop = 1
    while widthLoop == 1:
        try :
            width = float(width)
            break
        except :
            print ("Invalid input please TRY AGAIN !!!")
```

```
                #Length
                sampleValueForLength = 1
                length (sampleValueForLength)
                    
                #Width       
                sampleValueForWidth = 1
                width (sampleValueForWidth)
                    
                rectanglearea (length, width)
```

i tried like this :

```
#Area Of Rectangle Section
def rectanglearea(a, b):
    length = a
    width = b
    **area = length (a) * width (a)**
    print ("")
    print ("Formula = Length X Width")
    print ("Area Of This Rectangle Is: ", area)
```

Comment: sorry, but this code is a mess.  length() and width() don't return any values, don't use the parameter that is passed to them, use the function name as a variable name, probably other problems

Comment: You don't return a value from the functions `length` and `width`. Additionally  you overwrite those functions with the values `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need your function(s) to return values and be careful with your naming so you don't use the same name for variables and functions which will only confuse you if not the compiler.

Here is simple version to demonstrate:

```py
def prompt(s):
    while True:
        try:
            w = float(input(f'{s}: '))
            return w
        except:
            print('Invaid, try again')

            
prompt('Length') * prompt('Width')
```

```
Length: 2
Width: 3
6.0
```